# Sum two aggregations with different results and keep all

Tags: prometheus, promql

I would like create a list of all servers and aggregate them by teams. If I do this with a single metric this is easy:

For Linux: `count(node_uname_info) by (team)`
And Windows: `count(wmi_os_info) by (team)`

But now I want to aggregate this two queries to one as I want to get count of total servers by team.

Normally I would do it like that:
`count(node_uname_info) by (team) + count(wmi_os_info) by (team)`

But now I get only the teams which own both Linux and Windows servers.
Is there a way to assume that a value is zero if it is not existent?

Queries I have tried:

```
count(node_uname_info) by (team) + count(wmi_os_info) by (team)
count(node_uname_info) by (team) + (count(wmi_os_info) by (team) > 0)
count(node_uname_info) by (team) + on(team) count(wmi_os_info) by (team)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation about [binary operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators), the elements that do not match are not part of the result:

> Between two instant vectors, a binary arithmetic operator is applied to each entry in the left-hand side vector and its matching element in the right-hand vector[...]
>   Entries for which no matching entry in the right-hand vector can be found are not part of the result.

But you can select multiple metrics using the `__name__` internal label (see [selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors)) and the apply the `count` on the resulting vector:

```
count({__name__=~"node_uname_info|wmi_os_info"}) by (team)
```